# correct usage of will

Tags: grammar, will-would

> "I guarantee you that not only will the means negatively affect the relationship but the room won't stay clean when you leave town for a few days."

I just wonder if we can use "will" this way:

> "I guarantee you that not only the means will negatively affect the relationship but the room won't stay clean when you leave town for a few days."

Is this still grammatically correct?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also

Comment: Not sure about grammatical correctness, but it 'feels' wrong.